# Undefined reference to std::bad_cast::bad_cast()

Tags: c++, cmake, clang, linker-errors, undefined-reference

I am using cmake with clang++ on linux. I have run into a bit of linker trouble:

```
Linking CXX executable "/run/media/toi/Storage E/Dropbox/Programmering/Flictus/bin/main"
CMakeFiles/main.dir/GraphicsEngine/Shader.cpp.o:/run/media/toi/Storage E/Dropbox/Programmering/Flictus/src/GraphicsEngine/Shader.cpp:function std::__1::basic_filebuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::seekoff(long long, std::__1::ios_base::seekdir, unsigned int): error: undefined reference to 'std::bad_cast::bad_cast()'
CMakeFiles/main.dir/GraphicsEngine/Shader.cpp.o:/run/media/toi/Storage E/Dropbox/Programmering/Flictus/src/GraphicsEngine/Shader.cpp:function std::__1::basic_filebuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::sync(): error: undefined reference to 'std::bad_cast::bad_cast()'
CMakeFiles/main.dir/GraphicsEngine/Shader.cpp.o:/run/media/toi/Storage E/Dropbox/Programmering/Flictus/src/GraphicsEngine/Shader.cpp:function std::__1::basic_filebuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::underflow(): error: undefined reference to 'std::bad_cast::bad_cast()'
CMakeFiles/main.dir/GraphicsEngine/Shader.cpp.o:/run/media/toi/Storage E/Dropbox/Programmering/Flictus/src/GraphicsEngine/Shader.cpp:function std::__1::basic_filebuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::overflow(int): error: undefined reference to 'std::bad_cast::bad_cast()'
```

I'm assuming it is indeed a linker problem since it occurs after linking begins and the relevant headers are included.

I don't get undefined references on `std::cout` and such.

The code generating the linker error:

```
std::ifstream file(shaderFile, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
if (file) {
    file.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    shaderString.resize(file.tellg());
    file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
    file.read(&shaderString[0], shaderString.size());
    file.close();
}
```

The project ran fine until above code was added. It runs in Visual Studio 2013 with no problems.

Relevant parts of the cmake files:

```
add_compile_options(-stdlib=libc++)
add_compile_options(-std=c++1y)
set(CMAKE_LINKER /usr/bin/clang++) # didn't help when added
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-lc++ -Wall -fexceptions")
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER /usr/bin/clang++)
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER /usr/bin/clang)
```

So is there something more i should link with or is it a limitation in clang++?

**EDIT:** Linker invocation:

```
"/usr/bin/ld.gold" -export-dynamic --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -o 
/run/media/toi/Storage E/Dropbox/Programmering/Flictus/bin/main /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.8.2/../../../../lib64/crt1.o /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.8.2/../../../../lib64/crti.o 
/usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.8.2/crtbegin.o -L/usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.8.2 -L/usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.8.2/../../../../lib64 -L/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.8.2/../../.. -L/lib
 -L/usr/lib CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.o CMakeFiles/main.dir/GraphicsEngine/GraphicsEngine.cpp.o CMakeFiles/main.dir/GraphicsEngine/Shader.cpp.o 
CMakeFiles/main.dir/GraphicsEngine/TextureLoader.cpp.o CMakeFiles/main.dir/Input/Gamepad.cpp.o CMakeFiles/main.dir/Input/Input.cpp.o CMakeFiles/main.dir/GUI/Font.cpp.o CMakeFiles/main.dir/GUI/GUIEngine.cpp.o 
CMakeFiles/main.dir/GUI/GUIRect.cpp.o CMakeFiles/main.dir/GUI/GUISprite.cpp.o CMakeFiles/main.dir/GUI/Objects/Components/GUIText.cpp.o CMakeFiles/main.dir/GUI/Objects/GUIButton.cpp.o 
CMakeFiles/main.dir/GUI/Objects/GUIImage.cpp.o CMakeFiles/main.dir/GUI/Objects/GUILabel.cpp.o CMakeFiles/main.dir/GUI/Objects/GUIListBox.cpp.o 
CMakeFiles/main.dir/GUI/Objects/GUIObject.cpp.o -lSDL2 -lpthread -lGLEW -lGL -lSOIL -lc++ -lfreetype -lstdc++ -lm -lgcc_s -lgcc -lc -lgcc_s -lgcc /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.8.2/crtend.o /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.8.2/../../../../lib64/crtn.o
```

Answer (score 1):

This was solved by linking with `libc++abi`.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't done so already try compiling your code with the prefix g++ instead of gcc EX:

```
g++ (file name) :  gcc (file name)
```

The first one is correct.

The reason for this is because using the g++ prefix allows a different library of code to run.